# Nginx configuration issue with application

Tags: nginx, artifactory, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have an application which is running on http://artifactory.server.com:8082 and I have nginx.conf, The problem is that each time I'm trying to access http://artifactory.server.com/ it redirects me to http://artifactory.server.com/en-US/index.html, but I need to be redirected to this link http://artifactory.server.com:8082 . How can I resolve my issue?

```
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server {

          listen 80;
          server_name artifactory.server.com;


          location / {
              proxy_pass  http://artifactory.server.com:8082;
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: The solution looks correct - the redirect is not in the code you posted. I would comment out the include for a second, to see if there is something in there that redirects.

Comment: @Markido, tried your solution, got the same result after restarting nginx

Comment: The redirect you dont like is not in this confic, so it must be somewhere else, happening before. Try to catch that traffic instead. "location /en-US/index.html { proxy_pass http://artifactory.server.com:8082; }

Comment: @Markido, you think it is a good idea to going this way?

Comment: Its a hack for sure - id figure out what is doing the original redirect, and remove that

Comment: @Markido, I tried, but your solution does not work

Comment: it still redirecting me to this page

Comment: then your config probably has zero effect.